# adding a new column (= index.diff()) to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
>>> d.head()
Out[11]: 
                                      SOURCE
Time                                        
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00                 g
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00          h
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00          h
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00          f
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00          r

>>> d.index
Out[17]: 
DatetimeIndex([ '2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00', '2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00',...'2017-06-20 04:58:49.685000+08:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Time', length=783743, freq=None, tz='Asia/Singapore')
```

I want to add a new column , which equals the time difference between successive readings. I am trying these but none work:

1.

```
d['timediff']= d.index.diff()
```

2.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(d.index)
d['timediff']= temp.diff().iloc[:,0]
```

3.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(d.index)
d['timediff']=  pd.Series(temp.diff().iloc[:,0], index=d.index)
```

4.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(d.index)
d.assign(td=temp.diff())
```

All of these lead to NaNs in the 'timediff' column.

Finally this works:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(d.index)
temp = temp.diff().iloc[:,0].values
d = d.assign(timediff = temp)
```

Can someone clarify what's happening here? Just for ref, this is what i get for temp.diff:

```
>>> temp.diff().iloc[0:5,0]
Out[13]: 
0                       NaN
1    0 days 00:00:02.744000
2    0 days 00:00:07.424000
3    0 days 00:00:09.950000
4    0 days 00:00:28.498000
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

In addition, I have another (minor) question- the index for d reads like '2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00' . This happens after I convert the timezone of the index. Any idea what +8:00 refers to in each index value?

Comment: Timezone of GMT+8 hours suggests that you could head due north or south and wind up approximately in Singapore.

Comment: ok so +8:00 only refers to difference between Singapore vs GMT. The value before +8:00 , which is '2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000' is the actual Singapore time and doesnt need any adjustment? In other words, I can just ignore +8:00 if I want Singapore time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) first, because `index.diff()` is not implemented yet.

Also is necessary same index of new `Series` as original, else get `NaT`s:

```
print (d.index.to_series())
Time
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00          2017-04-03 01:05:07.000
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00   2017-04-03 01:05:09.744
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00   2017-04-03 01:05:17.168
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00   2017-04-03 01:05:27.118
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00   2017-04-03 01:05:55.616
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

d['diff'] = d.index.to_series().diff()
print (d)
                                 SOURCE            diff
Time                                                   
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00             g             NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00      h 00:00:02.744000
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00      h 00:00:07.424000
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00      f 00:00:09.950000
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00      r 00:00:28.498000
```

---

```
print (pd.Series(d.index))
0          2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00
1   2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00
2   2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00
3   2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00
4   2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns, Asia/Singapore]

d['diff'] = pd.Series(d.index).diff()
print (d)
                                 SOURCE diff
Time                                        
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00             g  NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00      h  NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00      h  NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00      f  NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00      r  NaT
```

With converting to `DataFrame` need assign `index` too and select column to`Series`:

```
d['diff'] = pd.DataFrame(d.index, index=d.index)['Time'].diff()
print (d)
                                 SOURCE            diff
Time                                                   
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00             g             NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00      h 00:00:02.744000
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00      h 00:00:07.424000
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00      f 00:00:09.950000
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00      r 00:00:28.498000
```

---

```
d['diff'] = pd.DataFrame(d.index, index=d.index).iloc[:, 0].diff()
print (d)
                                 SOURCE            diff
Time                                                   
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00             g             NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00      h 00:00:02.744000
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00      h 00:00:07.424000
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00      f 00:00:09.950000
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00      r 00:00:28.498000
```

Last version of pandas working with timezones perfectly. If need convert index to `UTC` need [`DatetimeIndex.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_convert.html) or [`DataFrame.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert.html):

```
d.index = d.index.tz_convert('UTC')
print (d)
                                 SOURCE
Time                                   
2017-04-03 01:05:07+00:00             g
2017-04-03 01:05:09.744000+00:00      h
2017-04-03 01:05:17.168000+00:00      h
2017-04-03 01:05:27.118000+00:00      f
2017-04-03 01:05:55.616000+00:00      r
```

---

```
d = d.tz_convert('UTC')
print (d)
                                 SOURCE
Time                                   
2017-04-03 01:05:07+00:00             g
2017-04-03 01:05:09.744000+00:00      h
2017-04-03 01:05:17.168000+00:00      h
2017-04-03 01:05:27.118000+00:00      f
2017-04-03 01:05:55.616000+00:00      r
```

And for remove `timezone`s from `DatetieIndex`:

```
d = d.tz_convert('UTC').tz_localize(None)
print (d)
                        SOURCE
Time                          
2017-04-03 01:05:07.000      g
2017-04-03 01:05:09.744      h
2017-04-03 01:05:17.168      h
2017-04-03 01:05:27.118      f
2017-04-03 01:05:55.616      r
```

But be aware or remove only - it simply remove `+8:00` and get diffferent time:

```
d = d.tz_localize(None)
print (d)
                        SOURCE
Time                          
2017-04-03 09:05:07.000      g
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744      h
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168      h
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118      f
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616      r
```

See difference:

```
d = d.tz_convert('UTC').tz_localize(None).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Singapore')
print (d)
                                 SOURCE
Time                                   
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00             g
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00      h
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00      h
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00      f
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00      r
```

vs

```
d = d.tz_localize(None).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Singapore')
print (d)
                                 SOURCE
Time                                   
2017-04-03 17:05:07+08:00             g
2017-04-03 17:05:09.744000+08:00      h
2017-04-03 17:05:17.168000+08:00      h
2017-04-03 17:05:27.118000+08:00      f
2017-04-03 17:05:55.616000+08:00      r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>> df
                                 SOURCE
Time                                   
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00             g
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00      h
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00      h
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00      f
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00      r
```

Since you cannot use `.diff()` on the index, convert it to a column first:

```
>>>> df['Time'] = df.index
>>>> df
                                 SOURCE                             Time
Time                                                                    
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00             g        2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00      h 2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00      h 2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00      f 2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00      r 2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00
```

And then it works fine:

```
>>>> df['Time'].diff()

Time
2017-04-03 09:05:07+08:00                      NaT
2017-04-03 09:05:09.744000+08:00   00:00:02.744000
2017-04-03 09:05:17.168000+08:00   00:00:07.424000
2017-04-03 09:05:27.118000+08:00   00:00:09.950000
2017-04-03 09:05:55.616000+08:00   00:00:28.498000
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```